# Filtering in Django Model Form where the user inputs the filter values

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-queryset

I am quite new to django and although my enthusiasm I am stuck to the below:

I have the model

```
class Task(models.Model):
    Taskdetails = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    asset = models.ForeignKey('Asset', null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

and I have created several objects with the ModelForm technique

I want to create a template that a user can choose an asset and by pressing the button to display all the tasks that are connected with this asset. I mention that an asset has many tasks. I am trying to do that using Django ModelForm.

So, I created first of all the form

```
class HistoryForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields =('asset',)
```

Then  I created the view "history" where a user can choose the asset that is interested:

```
def history(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        hist_form = HistoryForm(request.POST)
        if hist_form.is_valid():
           hist = hist_form.save(commit=False)
           hist.save()
           return ('results')
    else:
       hist_form = HistoryForm()

    return render(request, 'TaskTrace/history.html', {'hist_form': hist_form}
```

The html tag (part of it) is the below

```
{{ hist_form }}
<p><a href="{% url 'results'  %}"> <button type="submit" > Results</button></a></p>
```

Then I want to take the choice that the user made and transfer it to the next view ('results')

```
def results(request):
    tasks = Task.objects.filter(asset=request.POST.get('asset', None))
    return render(request, 'Tasktrace/results.html', {'tasks': tasks})
```

And the hmtl template is

```
{% for task in tasks %}
    <div>
        <p><a href=""><u>{{ task }}  </a></p>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

The problem is that I do not get any tasks. I believe that my big problem is to transfer the value from the first view to the other.

Is it the correct way to do the filtering in ModelForms? I probably miss something here

I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very very close.

Inside the `history.html` write the form like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'results' %}">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ hist_form }}
    <input type="submit" name="submit_results" value="Results" />
</form>
```

Now, the above form will be submitted to the `results` view and there you will get any `POST` data (as you already do, `request.POST.get('asset', None)`).

Comment: Lifesaver :) Thank you! Works Great!

Comment: The other problem I face is that when I do not choose any asset, the results page does not display but an error occurs: ValueError at /results/
invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''  My thought is when the user will not choose any asset, then all the tasks wil appear in the result page.    Is there any possible way to solve that?

Comment: Could you please show at which line this error occurs? It is shown in the traceback.

Comment: I think that the problem can be solved using `if not`.. I mean `if not request.POST.get('asset', None)` then `do something`. It seems to work